# Is there any way to do flash data in asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, flashvars

for more info of what I mean here is a quote from the user guide of the php mvc framework CodeIgniter

> CodeIgniter supports "flashdata", or session data that will only be available for the next server request, and are then automatically cleared. These can be very useful, and are typically used for informational or status messages (for example: "record 2 deleted").

..Something like that is what I need

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please check TempData in asp.net mvc.
Explanation by Phil Haack [here](http://haacked.com/archive/2007/12/21/asp.net-mvc-helpers-for-repopulating-a-form.aspx)